# UWP: Checkboxes in MenuItem show up blank

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to create a file menu that when opened, displays a series of checkbox options.

```
<controls:MenuItem Header="_Balancing" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="108">
      <CheckBox x:Name="menuBalancingEnable" IsChecked ="True" Unchecked="menuBalancingEnable_Unchecked"/>
      <CheckBox x:Name="menuBalancingActive" IsChecked="True" IsEnabled="False"/>
      <CheckBox x:Name="menuBalancingPassive" IsEnabled="False"/>
</controls:MenuItem>
```

However when I try it out, I end up with a blank menu bar. It has 3 entries, which is correct, but no checkbox or text! What am I missing?

[Menu with blank spaces instead of checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGy7U.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your CheckBox inside MenuFlyoutItem. Please refer below code:

```
<MenuFlyoutItem>
   <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
         <CheckBox x:Name="menuBalancingEnable" Content="Checkbox 1"  IsChecked ="True" />
     </ControlTemplate>
   </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
</MenuFlyoutItem>

<MenuFlyoutItem>
   <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
         <CheckBox x:Name="menuBalancingActive" Content="Checkbox 2"  IsEnabled="False"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
</MenuFlyoutItem>

<MenuFlyoutItem>
  <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
       <CheckBox x:Name="menuBalancingPassive" Content="Checkbox 3"  IsEnabled="False"/>
     </ControlTemplate>
  </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
</MenuFlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Hi @Dishant, i actually did try that, but when I do that I can no longer access the check box from the code-behind for some reason! Any idea why?

Also, Why doesn't it work in a MenuItem? Visual Studio seems to think that it is a valid entry (no error), and I do see three menu boxes when i run the app (however they are blank).

Comment: @Stepen The reason CheckBox dosen't work with MenuItem is because "[MenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.menuitem) is inheriting from `ItemsControl` and the allowed controls must be derived from `MenuFlyoutItemBase` like `MenuFlyoutSubItem`, `MenuFlyoutItem`, etc..." Refer [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/master/docs/controls/Menu.md)

Comment: To answer your question "but when I do that I can no longer access the check box from the code-behind for some reason! Any idea why?" - I would recommend you to open another SO thread.

Comment: Thanks @Dishant, that was going to be my next move if I couldn't get a working solution with MenuItem. I will open another thread. I should also file an issue with visual studio as they should mark a compile error for this.